# Instanceof - adding new object to a new ArrayList, from a previous ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, types, instanceof

I have a question regarding instanceof operator and how they are to be used correctly for my problem.

I currently have an ArrayList of type **Question**, which has two types stored **'QuestionType1'** and **'QuestionType2'**. There are **20** question objects stored and I need to randomly generate **5** from this list and store them some place new.

I have created a method which randomly generates the 5 questions, but I have become stuck on how to add them to a new ArrayList of type **'Question'**.

I used the instanceof operator to check if the returned questions match a certain type, then I would add them to the new ArrayList. (See code block Below).

```
    public static void chooseQuestions() {
    Random randomiser = new Random();
    Collections.shuffle(questions);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
        Question random = questions.get(randomiser.nextInt(questions.size()));
        System.out.println(random);

        if(random instanceof QuestionType1) {

            fiveQuestions().add(new QuestionType1(i, null, null, null, null, null, null, i) );

        } else if (random instanceof QuestionType2) {

            fiveQuestions().add(new QuestionType2(i, null, null, 1));
        }
    }

}
```

I just would like some help to know if:

- I used instanceof correctly
- what to replace the null placeholders with in the two 'fiveQuestions().add(new...'

Hopefully this is easy enough to read.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you simply add the 5 questions themselves, instead of creating new ones?

Comment: Why don't you put the "random" object into the list instead of creating a new question?

Comment: Whoops @JBNizet, you were faster :P

Comment: Thanks guys for the swift response ! got it working as expected ! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {
    Question random = questions.get(randomiser.nextInt(questions.size()));
    fiveQuestions().add(random);
}
```

Comment: because he creates new questions, not copies old ones

Comment: This is the correct answer, i'll mark it as it as soon as it allows me :) Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Question should have a type(like `QuestionType`), it should not be a `Question` itself. It is a HAS-A, not IS-A.

If you do this, you will just have to add the `Question` without checking it's actual type with instanceof and you will not have to copy the question. This will also solve the null part in the `fiveQuestions().add(....)` part.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you are using instanceof correctly
2. Instead of making a new question every time why not just replace this:

   ```
   fiveQuestions().add(new QuestionType2(i, null, null, 1));
   ```

   With:

   ```
   fiveQuestions().add(random);
   ```

If you really want to create new Questions you would have to tell us what the Question constructor is for us to tell you what to replace the `nulls` with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you used `instanceof` correctly.

To get rid of nulls in constructors you could create new constructor with only necessary params or consider using Builder pattern (however, it could be too complicated for such task).